# find and cat to merge csv files

Tags: shell, find, cat

I have thousands of files in sub-directories of ~/data. I wish to merge all those csv files with a certain extension say .x and save the merged file to ~/data/merged.x

I know I need to use find,cat and >> with the option -iname, but I'm finding it hard to do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find ~/data -name "*.x" | while read file
do
    cat $file >> ~/data/merged.x
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find ~/data -type f ! -name 'merged.x' -a -name '*.x' -exec cat {} \+ >> ~/data/merged.x
```

Comment: I missed the `! -name 'merged.x'` and it seemed to run forever; I killed it when I saw the `merged.x` file was over 70GB (should have been around 200MB). Without the not conditional, you can end up in an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./data/ -type f -name "*.c*" | xargs cat > ~/data/merged.x
```

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to run forever; killed when I saw the `merged.x` file was over 70GB (should have been around 200MB).