# Bash: tail, find, and cat

Tags: bash

I have one csv file in each subdirectory (each subdirectory is called RUN1, RUN2, etc) that starts with 'mod'. I want to find them, get the last line from each, and create a new file that contains only those lines. For example, if mod1.csv in subdirectory RUN1 has:

```
1, 2, 3

4, 5, 6
```

and mod2.csv in subdirectory RUN2 has

```
6,7,8

10,11,12
```

I want to create a new file results.csv that contains

```
4, 5, 6

10, 11, 12
```

Here's my attempt:

```
find $(pwd)/RUN* -name 'mod*.csv' tail -n +1 |xargs cat > results.csv
```

The error I'm getting is

```
    find: paths must precede expression: tail
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

I've [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790231/find-and-cat-to-merge-csv-files) but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing "-exec"

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell, but where should I put it? Still fairly new to bash.

Comment: By the way, the `find` program has nothing to do with `bash`.  It is independent, not a shell built-in, and can be called from any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Chepner forgot to tell -exec what is going to tail:

```
find ./RUN* -name 'mod*.csv' -exec tail -1 {} \; > results.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `-exec` primary, and you shouldn't need `xargs`:

```
find ./RUN* -name 'mod*.csv' -exec tail -n +1 {} \; > results.csv
```

Your `xarg` command would take the last line of each file, and treat that as a filename.

Comment: How long should this take to run? I'm not sure if my process is hanging....

Comment: Most of the running time should be spent searching (recursively) in `.` to find matching files. You can run `find ./RUN* -name 'mod*.csv'` to simply list the CSV files involved.

Comment: Listing the files takes less than 5 seconds. There's only one matching file per subdirectory. Is there any way to speed this up? It's taken 5 minutes so far.

Comment: Sorry, I confused how `-exec` works with `xargs` for a bit. You need an explicit `{}` argument for `tail`; right now, the first `tail` is blocking while trying to read from its standard input.